# <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">

Tags: php, mysql, post

I cannot understand why, in the following code, the else clause is never performed.  The form is displayed, but when I press the Submit button nothing happens.  Can anyone help?   Cheers.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset = "utf-8">
    <title>Listing 12-3</title>
</head>

<body>
<h1>Query the Shop Database</h1>
<h3>Search for a Product</h3>
<p> Use a wildcard if necessary - % in front / behind text</p>
<?php
    tryagain:
    // Wait for submit
    if (!$_POST['submit']) {
?>
    <form action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
        <p> Product Name: <input type ="text" name="product" /></p>
        <p><input type="submit" name = "submit" value = "Submit" /></p>
    </form>
<?php

        }
        else {
            // Connect to the Shop database
```

Comment: Shouldn't the line `tryagain:` be commented out?

Comment: Unrelated top tip: if you are just posting to the same page, then you don't need an `action` attribute. The current url will be the default `action`. Also when you say nothing happens, can you elaborate? Your example seems to be missing some code - you have an unclosed, empty `else` clause, and you have a `goto` label as well...

Comment: There's probably another error in your code that stops the script from executing. Check your PHP file for syntax errors (`php -l $file`) and fix any errors that show up. Then, add a `die('else');` right at the beginning of the `else` block to see if it really doesn't get executed.

Comment: You have some badly formatted HTML code, there should be no spaces between attribute names and the values, this could be causing your "**else clause is never performed**", should be something such as `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />` and as @Darragh has said, you do not need the action, it will post to itself without this

Answer (score 1):

Please change

```
if (!$_POST['submit']) {
```

to

```
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) {
```